# Is the "close" flag right for this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Recently I asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138298). Within a few minutes it got flagged for 'close'. They stated that **I should not post images and other things rather I should use code, data, error messages, etc.** Though those images were as additional information and proof that I am suffering of a technical issue which is **not code based**. I got flagged again after a while.

I clearly understand why it is important, but I am here to ask exactly what is wrong with my question and what is the correct way to ask the same without using images?

Comment: IMO images are fine if useful information from the image can't be communicated as easily as text, or to provide clear proof of what's going on. I think the issue with the question is not the images, but that it looks like more of a software support question than a programming question, and so doesn't quite belong here, despite the software being programming-related

Comment: I agree with you that the question might not belongs to there because its not a programming issue but I have seen many questions over there similar to that, are related to system configurations, those questions are running and helping successfully. So I took my chances.

Comment: Use text for what can be given in text.

Comment: I did, I stated everything Image representing in question. Images are proof that I am not messing around and out of those three Images, We can't properly provide first image's data in text because it was not available in that form.

Comment: Yeah, AS has a memory leak. Report a bug. Restart every once in a while.

Comment: @DavyMwenttofundMonica not sure I 100% agree there. Why shouldn't this be handled like any other normal usermode application that causes havoc on a machine? If the mediaplayer leaks memory the diagnosing and handling is the same. You probably get more help out of experts that are familiar with the OS and its diagnosing tools for a wide range of applications.

Comment: @Rene Thanks, I'm (likely erroneously) assuming that the close voter was the same as the commenter who wrote in big bold letters "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.", and I also assumed the close vote reason was for not containing all the information in the question itself due to being in images instead of text. Re-reading, I see that assumed too far, since it wouldn't be over zealous at all to suggest closure as a general computing software issue. You know what they say about [assumptions](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Assume)... I should know better :)

Comment: When you have a big bold line that says it’s not a coding question, it’s very likely not on-topic for Stack Overflow...

Comment: @CodyGray I wrote that line because the comment after it got "flagged" was saying to post code or message. It is very clear that in my issue neither I have any code nor a message. And the reason I asked that question over SO is that there could be many reason and fixes of problem which might be directly related to some AS config or JAVA argument. This is also not a coding issue but related to it. I personally think that question belongs to SO but its a community and it has some rule. I was bit confused about `Rules`.

Comment: It's not `directly` linked to SU or L&U sites just because of I was using it as OS. Ask Ubuntu is right platform though. We should not forget that macOS also runs on Unix and if I have any issue related to Xcode, which site you gonna suggest to ask a question on ?

Comment: People might not think all the aspects before flag/vote. "I think it has no code oh thats should not be on SO" -- anything on a computer having an issue is DIRECTLY related CODE either firmware level or software level. It was not MY code which was causing the issue. This is what that line meant.

Comment: What is `Rules`? What does that have to do with programming? If it's not a programming issue, it's not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BlindNinja - I think everyone realizes the situation you present. There is an issue with the IDE not properly behaving either by itself or with the Operating System. However, some users, such as the ones who closed your question, do not believe those questions are on topic at Stack Overflow. The "on topic" debate took place 5 years ago, and hasn't changed, so they aren't necessarily wrong. It's just that IDE environment settings are to some degree on topic, so perhaps we should make it clearer somewhere where the line is there.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: I rolled back your update. One question per post, please. Ask a new question with a specific topic and  adequate background (link back here for context if you think it makes sense).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to be bold here, but I say yes, that closure is right. The question is off-topic. It is well-asked in my opinion, despite the claims in the comments.

Here is my reasoning.

While Android Studio is a tool often used by programmers, the specific issue is not about using the features of Android Studio. It is more about an installation/setup/operating system/host kind of problem. There are way more things to consider than just the use of Android Studio itself.

In that context, I think the question is on-topic on the sites that have usermode applications as their area of expertise. I think of [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). I presume that the expert on that site are able to offer more detailed answers, diagnosing options, workarounds for any memory leaking application and that includes Android Studio. You might have to provide some specific stuff, for example if Android Studio is a typical JVM driven app but from there users can apply all their knowledge from other/similar setups.

It is true that, due to the nature of Android Studio, it is likely you find more users on SO that have experienced or are experiencing the same problem. Some of those users, due to their problem solving and tech savvy background, might have dived in and found either a root cause, a workaround or a patch. Those answers would still be useful on the other sites I mentioned.

Comment: +1, You are right. I will ask the same question on Super User and Unix & Linux. Ask Ubuntu already have exactly same question but no answer is accepted and nothing helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: @BlindNinja please don't cross post. Consider asking in chat first.

Comment: I don't really disagree with your assertion in the current environment, but is this really an ideal position to be in for Stack Overflow? Should we be disallowing well asked questions related to developing software where the fix is to alter some aspect of the development environment?

Comment: @TravisJ yeah, that is a valid argument. I was hoping you or others would make that argument. I certainly would appreciate if you wrote a competing answer. I think the crucial aspect here is whether specific aspects of the OS or VM that might cause your IDE to fail are indeed on topic of SO. It is a blurry line and I added enough fuzzyness with my answer. Take your turn, please.

Comment: @rene - I was mostly curious on your take of the situation, not in writing an answer which suggests we go in that direction for this specific question. You can see my point of view for expanding and reviewing close reasons in my recent posts though, and at some point hopefully there will be some empirical evidence and a fr.

Comment: @TravisJ I have wrote some comment under the question, I want your feedback on those comments. Thanks.

Comment: and @rene your's too.